# WebStorm says dropDatabase is an function type

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, webstorm

Using WebStorm 10.0

I am using mongoDB and I have a unresolved function/method warning when I use **db**, **dropDatabase**.

I had searched a plugin in frameworks and languages inside the WebStorm but I could not find any. How do I fix it in WebStorm?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If it done like that it's gonna give out type error

Comment: Adding mongoose.d.ts as JavaScript library in Preferences | Languages and Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries helps to resolve db, but there's no dropDatabase defined in this TypeScript definition file, that is why it's unresolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some times dropDatabase not work when the connection is opened or live ,but you can still use the regular formal preferred approach

```
var conn, mongoose;
mongoose = require("mongoose");
conn = mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/mydb");

conn.connection.db.dropDatabase();
```